# Apache Nutch does not index the entire website, only subfolders

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

Apache Nutch 1.2 does not index the entire website, only subfolders. My index-page provides links in most areas/subfolders of my website. For example stuff, students, research... But nutch only crawl in one specific folder - "students" in this case. Seems as if links in other directories are not followed.

crawl-urlfilter.txt:
+^http://www5.my-domain.de/

seed.txt in the URLs-folder:
http://www5.my-domain.de/

Starting nutch with(windows/linux both used):
nutch crawl "D:\Programme\nutch-1.2\URLs" -dir "D:\Programme\nutch-1.2\crawl" -depth 10 -topN 1000000

Different variants for depth(5-23) and topN(100-1000000) are tested. Providing more links in seed.txt doesnt help at all, still not following links found in injected pages.

Interestingly, crawling gnu.org works perfect. No robots.txt or preventing meta-tags used in my site.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you use paramaters for your site urls, because from the top of my head the default config filters out url with such things as ? = etc...

Comment: No, just PHP-Sites without Parameters.

Answer (score 2):

While attempting to crawl all links from an index page, I discovered that nutch was limited to exactly 100 links of around 1000. The setting that was holding me back was:

```
db.max.outlinks.per.page
```

Setting this to 2000 allowed nutch to index all of them in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

Check out if you´ve got intra domain links limitation (property as false in nutch-site.xml). Also check out other properties as maximun intra-extra links per page and http size. Sometimes they produce wrong results during crawling.

Ciao!